# Angular CLI fileReplacements for default/development

Tags: angular-cli, angular-cli-v7

I have a rather complex `angular.json` because I have multiple projects. What I would like to have is separate environment.ts files per project. Replacing the environment file when the build target is production seems to be pretty straightforward:

```
"configurations": {
  "production": {
    "fileReplacements": [
      {
        "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
        "with": "src/private-label/redacted/environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    ],
  }
}
```

What I'm looking for is a way to do the same with the default/development configuration. The `angular.json` does not contain a configuration node for anything like that that I can find and so I'm not sure if it is possible and/or where to specify `fileReplacements` when not targeting production.

Of course, if there is a better way to handle environments per project that I'm not seeing I would also be interested in that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I assume with *"default/development configuration"* you are referring to what is served with the `ng serve` command.

**Option 1: replace environment files:**

You can specify the `fileReplacements` array in the `build` object as well (this one is used for `ng serve`).

```
  "build": {
    "options": {
      [...]
      "fileReplacements": [
        {
          "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
          "with": "src/environments/environment.development.ts"
        }
      ]      
    },
    "configurations": {
      // other - non default - configurations 
    }
  }
```

**Option 2: specifiy default configuration:**

If you want to serve an already existing configuration with`ng serve`, you can change the `serve` options:

```
  "configurations": {
    "youConfigName": {
      // config details here
    }
  },
  [...]
  "serve": {
    "options": {
      "browserTarget": "name-of-your-app:build:youConfigName"
    }
  }
```

The important point is to set the build configuration target with `:yourConfigName`.

---

Both options are configured per project and therefore allow you full control.

Answer (score 3):

Also, be sure to execute the right command to start/serve your app. In my case, I'm using Azure Pipelines to deploy to Azure App Service, and the command is:

[image]

Note that, "--configuration=production" is mandatory in order to achieve the file replacement.

I also put the "fileReplacements" section in both: "build" and "configuration" section of the angular.json file<sup>1</sup>:

[image]

---

<sup>1</sup> In Angular 17 (and maybe earlier) you have to place `fileReplacements` block not **next to** `options`, but **inside it**. Also, bear in mind that `fileReplacements` inside `configurations -> production` [overwrite](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/16688) `fileReplacements` from outer `architect -> build -> options`. So if you need replacements from both, you have to merge them by hand and write all `fileReplacements` inside `configurations -> production`.

Comment: By placing your replacement outside the configuration does that mean you will always build in production ?  What is the command you use for DEV and for PROD in this scenario ?

Comment: @MarcRoussel there is only one configuration in "configurations" on the screenshot, so this project can only be built with "production" configuration. If you try to specify `--configuration=asdf` parameter in build command, you'll get an error.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @jowey is working but with a small extension for Angular 8. I had to prepend the url with ./

"replace": "./src/environments/environment.ts",
"with": "./src/environments/environment.development.ts"